# Connections to my servers remaining open using fsockopen(); in PHP to check their status

Tags: php

I've been coding up a quick web app to check the status of all the different dedicated server processes I run on my multi-purpose server. I'm using `fsockopen` to check the ports, and it's doing what I need it to do in that it's returning whether there is a service running on those ports, but it seems to be leaving the connections open. One specific instance is my Mumble server. Every time I run the script, it returns that my mumble server is online but the connection it opens with `fsockopen` is adding to the user count. It can keep going until it reaches the max user count and then will refuse connections from actual mumble clients as well as further attempts to check it with `fsockopen`. The same happens when running my server for Terraria. Eventually, after probably at least an hour, the user count on my mumble server is resetting but I'm not certain if it is the connections closing or the server crashing and restarting.

Here's the code I'm using to check the ports and display on the page their status:

```
function serverPort($port, $service) {
    $fp = @fsockopen("192.168.1.xxx", $port, $errno, $errstr, 3);
        if($fp) {
            $color = "green";
            echo "<span style='font:12px/0px monospace'><b>$service</b></span>".
            spacer($service)."<span style='font:12px/0px monospace'> | 
            <b><font color=$color>online</font></span></b>\n";
            fclose($fp);
        } else {
            $color = "red";
            echo "<span style='font:12px/0px monospace'><b>$service</b></span>".
        spacer($service)."<span style='font:12px/0px monospace'> | 
        <b><font color=$color>offline</font></span></b>\n";
        fclose($fp);
        }
    stream_set_timeout($fp, 1);
    fclose($fp);
    $fp = null;

    echo "</br>";
}
```

I've got a function called in this code for dynamic spacing (`spacer();`) on the output strings that is defined in the actual script prior to the function detailed here. It's not relevent to the problem but I've left it in there to reduce confusion on my own part.

As you can see near the end there I've tried three separate methods I've come across that I was under the impression were meant to close the connections but none of them have achieved the desired result. I'm relatively new to PHP in that I haven't touched it since probably '04, same for HTML, so anything helps at this point.

Also, for reference, I've tried `socket_create` and `socket_close` together separately from `fsockopen` and it wouldn't even echo my intended results.

Edit: And if anyone is curious, this is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNp6E.png

It's completely functional, it's just the issue of the connections remaining open I need solved.

Comment: take a look @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-blocking.php and tell me if it helped :) (default mode of fsockopen is blocking, so maybe thats from here)

Comment: @Bob0t I've looked into that, gave it a go, probably used it incorrectly, and turned up no results. The script will still run and display accurately the status of my servers but it continues leave ghost users on my servers, hogging all my client slots. I went ahead and went back to my previous code, commented out `error_reporting(0);` so that I could check for errors which I had no thought to do previously and am getting `Warning: fclose(): 2 is not a valid stream resource in C:\Apache24\index\index.php on line 89`. The `fclose` is demonstrated in my original post, do you see anything wrong?

Comment: ahah `ini_set('display_errors', true);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL)` is a need when you are in a developpement phase ;) hope you will find out what is giving you ghost users, btw thank you for giving me solution for easy mumble OOS attacks :v (i will not do that but thats fun to know ^^)

Comment: yep, there is something wrong, you have 2 `fclose($fp);` on each way, i mean, you have to delete `fclose($fp);` inside `if` and `else` :)

Comment: @Bob0t Lol, yeah, it's apparently very easy to DoS mumble servers with php and a refresh script.

I've gone ahead and removed the `fclose($fp);` within the `if` and `else` parts, and am now only receiving `Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Apache24\index\index.php on line 87` for offline server responses. Servers returning `online` are not throwing errors.

Comment: Cuz you dont check anymore if `$fp` returns `false` ^^ check it like a boss : `if($fp) fclose($fp);`

Comment: the boolean is from fsockopen() returning false when it can't connect

Comment: yep, btw for mumble and terraria, maybe you just need to `fwrite` socket with a disconnection query or something ... idk

Comment: @Bob0t That sounds like a good idea. Incidentally, I have absolutely no idea how to go about it! Any pointers? :D

Edit: I am officially error free on my web app frontend checking for `!$fp`. Now I just need to solve this issue with the phantom users on my server backend.

Answer (score 4):

found on php.net (http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php)

> It is very important to make sure you clear any incoming packets out of the incoming buffer 
>   using fread() or some equivalent.  Although you can call fclose() the socket does not 
>   actually shut down until the inbound packets have been cleared.  This can lead to some 
>   confusion.

and

> In case you have some trouble to properly disconnect some client streams opened with 
>   stream_socket_server / stream_select you should give a try to stream_socket_shutdown.
>
> <?php stream_socket_shutdown($clientStream,STREAM_SHUT_RDWR); ?>

Comment: Since adding `stream_socket_shutdown($fp, STREAM_SHUT_RDWR);` I've been spam running the script and have not seen additional phantom users on my Mumble server while the script still reports that it is online. This may have solved it. I need to test with my Terraria server as well. I will report back when I have done so. Thank you for your assistance :D

Comment: I guess I spoke too soon. The problem is still there.

Comment: does mumble need an explicit logout to decrement the user count?  Is the "phantom user" issue reproducible from the command line with nc?(or telnet?)  (and how long before these phantoms time out?)

Comment: It would appear, thankfully, that terraria clears these phantom users after 5-10 minutes or so. I can circumvent the problem there by setting the userlimit unnecessarily high. Mumble seems to either purge the phantom connections after upwards of an hour based on my trip to the store earlier and finding no connections when I returned. I'm currently enabling telnet and will report back when it finishes enabling.

Comment: Yes, the issue is able to be reproduced via telnet from the command line. Connecting via telnet will add to the usercount, and as with my script reporting "offline" when userlimits are reached, telnet will fail to connect as well.

Comment: Did you used `fread()` ? I'll try too, actually configuring a server to test it :3 if i find how to make it work properly i'll tell you :p

Comment: Ok, so i just configured out a server with mumble-server running ice, and mumble-django, apache, mysql, php5-fpm under debian7 evrything is ok i can fsock as much as i want, i never have ghost users ... btw, in logs i have this : `Ignoring connection: <my_ip>:<port> (Global ban)`

Comment: @Bob0t Bleh, I missed your comments because I did not see the "view 2 more comments" link thing. How would I go about setting up that global ban on my ip/port? Would that prevent me from connecting from my primary computer on the same LAN?

Comment: @ZackCampbell Idk, i just have this in my logs, but still able to connect to server so... no idea of what that excatly means :v

Comment: @Bob0t I ended up messing around with some things the other day, and I think I actually fixed the problem for myself. I haven't turned on logging, and I'm still getting connections pop up, but they're only lasting for about 30 seconds each now, which is a significant improvement.